# Implementing JPA query in Play for Scala

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.5

I'm trying to implement JPA in Play for Scala, following [these examples](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaJPA#Using-play.db.jpa.JPAApi) documented in Java.

In the following code I get a compilation error in `jpaApi.withTransaction`:

```
class ManageBanks @Inject() (jpaApi: JPAApi) extends Controller {

   @Transactional
   def readMany = {
      val em = jpaApi.em

      jpaApi.withTransaction( em -> {   //  <-- error in this line
          val query = em.createQuery("from BankHib order by name")
          val list = query.getResultList.asScala.toList.map(_.asInstanceOf[BankHib])
          list
      })
   }
}
```

The error:

> overloaded method value withTransaction with alternatives: (x$1:
>   Runnable)Unit  [T](x$1: java.util.function.Supplier[T])T 
>   [T](x$1:
>   java.util.function.Function[javax.persistence.EntityManager,T])T
>   cannot be applied to ((javax.persistence.EntityManager,
>   List[admin.manage.BankHib]))

What's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lambdas in Scala use syntax

```
em => ...
```

instead of

```
em -> ...
```

in Java.

`->` in Scala is for maps.